# twitter like button animation using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I found the animation code in web and when i click the image it's play the animation again to stating part. I want to do when i click the image it will play the animation and stop with animation again click it should be reset the image, anyone give me a feedback to how to do that..

```css
.like-btn-svg {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  bottom: -112px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: url(https://abs.twimg.com/a/1446542199/img/t1/web_heart_animation.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  animation: fave-like-btn-svg 1s steps(28);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.like-btn-svg:hover {
  background-position: -2800px 0;
  transition: background 1s steps(28);
}

@keyframes fave-like-btn-svg {
  0% {
    background-position: 2800px 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -2800px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="like-btn-svg"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jquery (or javaScript if you want) to toggle class for animation. I've updated your code, please take a look:

```js
$('.like-btn-svg').on('click', function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('animate');
});
```

```css
.like-btn-svg {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  bottom: 0; /* temp value */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: url(https://abs.twimg.com/a/1446542199/img/t1/web_heart_animation.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.like-btn-svg.animate {
  transition: background 1s steps(28);
  animation: fave-like-btn-svg 1s steps(28);
  background-position: -2800px 0;
}

@keyframes fave-like-btn-svg {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -2800px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="like-btn-svg"></div>
```

Answer (score 18):

### Pure CSS and SVG

```css
svg {
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 60px;
  margin: 20px;
}

svg #heart {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: animateHeartOut .3s linear forwards;
}

svg #main-circ {
  transform-origin: 29.5px 29.5px;
}

.checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #heart {
  transform: scale(0.2);
  fill: #E2264D;
  animation: animateHeart .3s linear forwards .25s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #main-circ {
  transition: all 2s;
  animation: animateCircle .3s linear forwards;
  opacity: 1;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp1 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s all .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp1 #oval1 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(0, -30px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp1 #oval2 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(10px, -50px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp2 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s all .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp2 #oval1 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(30px, -15px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp2 #oval2 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(60px, -15px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s all .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp3 #oval1 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(30px, 0px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp3 #oval2 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(60px, 10px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp4 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s all .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp4 #oval1 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(30px, 15px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp4 #oval2 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(40px, 50px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp5 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s all .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp5 #oval1 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(-10px, 20px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp5 #oval2 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(-60px, 30px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp6 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s all .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp6 #oval1 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(-30px, 0px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp6 #oval2 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(-60px, -5px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp7 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s all .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp7 #oval1 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(-30px, -15px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: .5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp7 #oval2 {
  transform: scale(0) translate(-55px, -30px);
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
  transition: 1.5s transform .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp2 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s opacity .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp3 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s opacity .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp4 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s opacity .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp5 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s opacity .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp6 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s opacity .3s;
}

.checkbox:checked+label svg #grp7 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .1s opacity .3s;
}

@keyframes animateCircle {
  40% {
    transform: scale(10);
    opacity: 1;
    fill: #DD4688;
  }
  55% {
    transform: scale(11);
    opacity: 1;
    fill: #D46ABF;
  }
  65% {
    transform: scale(12);
    opacity: 1;
    fill: #CC8EF5;
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(13);
    opacity: 1;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #CC8EF5;
    stroke-width: .5;
  }
  85% {
    transform: scale(17);
    opacity: 1;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #CC8EF5;
    stroke-width: .2;
  }
  95% {
    transform: scale(18);
    opacity: 1;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #CC8EF5;
    stroke-width: .1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(19);
    opacity: 1;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #CC8EF5;
    stroke-width: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes animateHeart {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes animateHeartOut {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox">
      <svg id="heart-svg" viewBox="467 392 58 57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="Group" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(467 392)">
          <path d="M29.144 20.773c-.063-.13-4.227-8.67-11.44-2.59C7.63 28.795 28.94 43.256 29.143 43.394c.204-.138 21.513-14.6 11.44-25.213-7.214-6.08-11.377 2.46-11.44 2.59z" id="heart" fill="#AAB8C2"/>
          <circle id="main-circ" fill="#E2264D" opacity="0" cx="29.5" cy="29.5" r="1.5"/>

          <g id="grp7" opacity="0" transform="translate(7 6)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#9CD8C3" cx="2" cy="6" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#8CE8C3" cx="5" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp6" opacity="0" transform="translate(0 28)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#CC8EF5" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#91D2FA" cx="3" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp3" opacity="0" transform="translate(52 28)">
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#9CD8C3" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#8CE8C3" cx="4" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp2" opacity="0" transform="translate(44 6)">
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#CC8EF5" cx="5" cy="6" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#CC8EF5" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp5" opacity="0" transform="translate(14 50)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#91D2FA" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#91D2FA" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp4" opacity="0" transform="translate(35 50)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#F48EA7" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#F48EA7" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp1" opacity="0" transform="translate(24)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#9FC7FA" cx="2.5" cy="3" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#9FC7FA" cx="7.5" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox_2" />
<label for="checkbox_2">
      <svg id="heart-svg" viewBox="467 392 58 57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="Group" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(467 392)">
          <path d="M29.144 20.773c-.063-.13-4.227-8.67-11.44-2.59C7.63 28.795 28.94 43.256 29.143 43.394c.204-.138 21.513-14.6 11.44-25.213-7.214-6.08-11.377 2.46-11.44 2.59z" id="heart" fill="#AAB8C2"/>
          <circle id="main-circ" fill="#E2264D" opacity="0" cx="29.5" cy="29.5" r="1.5"/>

          <g id="grp7" opacity="0" transform="translate(7 6)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#9CD8C3" cx="2" cy="6" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#8CE8C3" cx="5" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp6" opacity="0" transform="translate(0 28)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#CC8EF5" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#91D2FA" cx="3" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp3" opacity="0" transform="translate(52 28)">
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#9CD8C3" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#8CE8C3" cx="4" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp2" opacity="0" transform="translate(44 6)">
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#CC8EF5" cx="5" cy="6" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#CC8EF5" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp5" opacity="0" transform="translate(14 50)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#91D2FA" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#91D2FA" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp4" opacity="0" transform="translate(35 50)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#F48EA7" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#F48EA7" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp1" opacity="0" transform="translate(24)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#9FC7FA" cx="2.5" cy="3" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#9FC7FA" cx="7.5" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox_3" />
<label for="checkbox_3">
      <svg id="heart-svg" viewBox="467 392 58 57" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g id="Group" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(467 392)">
          <path d="M29.144 20.773c-.063-.13-4.227-8.67-11.44-2.59C7.63 28.795 28.94 43.256 29.143 43.394c.204-.138 21.513-14.6 11.44-25.213-7.214-6.08-11.377 2.46-11.44 2.59z" id="heart" fill="#AAB8C2"/>
          <circle id="main-circ" fill="#E2264D" opacity="0" cx="29.5" cy="29.5" r="1.5"/>

          <g id="grp7" opacity="0" transform="translate(7 6)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#9CD8C3" cx="2" cy="6" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#8CE8C3" cx="5" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp6" opacity="0" transform="translate(0 28)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#CC8EF5" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#91D2FA" cx="3" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp3" opacity="0" transform="translate(52 28)">
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#9CD8C3" cx="2" cy="7" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#8CE8C3" cx="4" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp2" opacity="0" transform="translate(44 6)">
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#CC8EF5" cx="5" cy="6" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#CC8EF5" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp5" opacity="0" transform="translate(14 50)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#91D2FA" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#91D2FA" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp4" opacity="0" transform="translate(35 50)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#F48EA7" cx="6" cy="5" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#F48EA7" cx="2" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>

          <g id="grp1" opacity="0" transform="translate(24)">
            <circle id="oval1" fill="#9FC7FA" cx="2.5" cy="3" r="2"/>
            <circle id="oval2" fill="#9FC7FA" cx="7.5" cy="2" r="2"/>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </label>
```

Comment: you code single post mean working but multiple post mean first image only working when click other image also please give me a solution for this issues

Comment: you can change ids with classes, I've updated code you need to use unique 'ids' and 'for' attributes

Comment: Thanks a lot, both of you, This post really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

with only css:

```css
.like-btn-svg {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://abs.twimg.com/a/1446542199/img/t1/web_heart_animation.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display:none;
}

input:checked + .like-btn-svg{
  transition: background 1s steps(28);
  animation: fave-like-btn-svg 1s steps(28);
  background-position: -2800px 0;
}

@keyframes fave-like-btn-svg {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -2800px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox">
  <div class="like-btn-svg"></div>
</label>
```